# Using environment variables to ssh into remote from Mac using Zsh

Tags: ssh, zsh

My local environment:

```
Mac Big Sur 11.6
Z shell
```

Remote system:

```
Ubuntu
```

What I would like to do is set a variable in my local environment and use that variable as my password when I ssh into the remote server, something like:

```
ssh user@sometesystem.com -p env(userpwd)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. Recommended, no. If you want to log in without typing your password, set up public-key authentication.

Comment: I have no choice, there is no key setup and there is no way to add one at this point

Comment: Useful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

Comment: If you can log into the remote machine, you can set up public-key authentication.

Comment: @Vincent This works if you have a key that requires a password

Comment: If your key requires a passphrase, you can add the passphrase to your Keychain, then use `ssh-add -A` to add any key found in the Keychain to your local SSH agent.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I know that I can set up a key if I have access to the remote machine, I don't. The passphrase comment was in response to the suggested answer on apple.stackexchange

Comment: Of course you have access to it. That's what `ssh` *does*: it provides access to the remote machine. The key gets created *locally*, and all you need to do is copy the public key to the remote host, which can be as simple as something like `ssh user@host 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/mykey_pub`.

Comment: @chepner ssh access for an account does not give me root/sudo access to the machine so I can create a key to use with my account

Comment: Again, you don't need root access on the remote end to create or install the key. *You* create the key on your local machine and simply copy the public key to the remote machine.